# Help with an irregular integral

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, fourier-analysis

I am looking for help with doing the following integral :
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{1-e^{-2\pi i x}}{1-e^{2\pi i x}} \right )\frac{dx}{x\left(\ln x+z\right)}\;\;\;\;z\in \mathbb{C}$$
i tried to transform it into a complex integral along a 'keyhole contour', with a branch cut along the +ive real line $\left[1,\infty\right)$. but then $\;\ln x\;$ would be transformed into $\;\ln x+2\pi i\;$ when doing the integral along the segment parallel to and below $\left(\infty,1\right]\;$  which doesn't add up nicely to the portion along the segment parallel to and above $\left[1,\infty\right)$  .

It can be shown that the above integral is equivalent to:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi n x)}{n\pi}\left(\frac{1}{x\left(\ln x+z\right)}\right)dx$$
And
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x+\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor  \right )\left(\frac{1}{x\left(\ln x+z\right)}\right)dx$$
EDIT:
Another way to think of it is to take the Taylor expansion of the $ \log $:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\ln\left(1-e^{-2\pi i x}\right)-\ln(1-e^{2\pi i x})\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i k x}-e^{-2\pi i kx}}{k}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi k x)}{k\pi}$$
Which in turn is the Fourier expansion of $\frac{1}{2}-x+\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor $.

Also, using the definition of the zeta function :
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_{1}^{\infty}(x-\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor )x^{-s-1}dx\;\;\;\;\;\Re(s)>0$$
We have:
$$\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}+\frac{1}{2s}-\frac{1}{s-1}=\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x+\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor\right)x^{-s-1}dx$$
And:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x+\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor  \right )\left(\frac{1}{x\left(\ln x+z\right)}\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}+\frac{1}{2s}-\frac{1}{s-1}\right)e^{-zs}ds$$

I posted this question on [MS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254668/help-with-an-irregular-integral), and got no answers, even with a bounty !! any insights are  appreciated.

Comment: mohammad-83 -- it's a bit difficult to answer this as you haven't told us what exactly you are trying to do with the integral: prove that it converges? find an estimate for its value? calculate the value explicitly in terms of $e$'s and $\pi$'s? In the latter case, why do you think the integral can be expressed in this form? And so on.

Comment: @algori .. thanks for your remarks. i updated the post so as to address your second question. i'm trying to do the integral explicitly as a function of the variable $z$. 

Comment: mohammad-83 -- your last integral is the Laplace transform of some function, so I would try to take look in some book on integral transforms. But it is not very clear why you expect that the result can be written in a nice form.

Comment: i don't expect a nice from at all, in fact, we can prove there is no one... i just need to compute the integral explicitly. 